# Sum integer value in dict when dict values have strings and integers

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, dictionary

Having a dictionary like

```
{'bob': (1, 'bob'), 'alicia': (3, 'alicia')}
```

How can I add for example 1 to value [0] in values() of 'bob' key?

So I want something like

```
{'bob': (2, 'bob'), 'alicia': (3, 'alicia')}
```

I've tried this

```
list1 = ['bob', 'alicia', 'bob'] 
d = {}
for i in list1:
    if i not in d:
        d = 1, i
    else:
        d += 1, i
```

But 'tuple' object does not support item assignment.

I do not want lists in values dictionary.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tuples are ment to be [immutable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-immutable). Thus, editing a tuple is a break of contract. If you want to change the value within the tuple, you will have to construct a new one.

```
data = {'bob': (1, 'bob'), 'alicia': (3, 'alicia')}
data['bob'] = (data['bob'][0] + 1, data['bob'][1])
print(data)

# Out[0]: {'bob': (2, 'bob'), 'alicia': (3, 'alicia')}
```

---

You could also create a mutable counter object that you store in the tuple, something along the lines of

```
class Counter:
    def __init__(self, start: int = 1):
        self._num = start

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._num

    def increment(self):
        self._num += 1

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._num)


data = {'bob': (Counter(), 'bob'), 'alicia': (Counter(3), 'alicia')}
data['bob'][0].increment()
print(data)

# Out[1]: {'bob': (2, 'bob'), 'alicia': (3, 'alicia')}
```

A nice discussion if the latter makes the tuple mutable or not (and therefore is a break of contract) can be found in the blog of [inventwithpython.com](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2018/02/05/python-tuples-are-immutable-except-when-theyre-mutable/).